# Manter espaçamentos entre elementos porem sem espaços entre Tags

Tags: html

Estou removendo `Todos` os espaços em branco de meus arquivos `HTML` visando ter uma boa redução de seu tamanho (em media 5%) porem quando o faço é removido o espaço em branco entre os elementos quando o `HTML` é renderizado no browser desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sinalizado com setas vermelhas onde ficavam os espaços em branco.

HTML Respectivo:

```
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1252616952/650camaro-3_normal.jpg"/><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1252616952/650camaro-3_normal.jpg"/><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1252616952/650camaro-3_normal.jpg"/>
```

Imagem do `HTML` com espaços entre tags renderizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML Respectivo:

```
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1252616952/650camaro-3_normal.jpg"/> <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1252616952/650camaro-3_normal.jpg"/> <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1252616952/650camaro-3_normal.jpg"/>
```

Como faço para obter os espaçamentos porem sem ter qualquer espaço entre tags? o espaçamento não deve gerar uma barra de rolagem horizontal (que acontece geralmente quando damanos um margin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize **`inline-block`** e aplique uma margem entre eles:

```css
img {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px
}
```

```html
<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ybwB.jpg' alt=''/><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ybwB.jpg' alt=''/><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ybwB.jpg' alt=''/><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ybwB.jpg' alt=''/>
```

Comment: .@re22, teria como isso ser mais global? porque desta forma teria de ir aplicando a cada elemento, haverá alguma interferência a elementos que possui outro tipo de "display:"

Comment: @RicardoHenrique o que seria global? Se tem mais alguma coisa pra especificar, edite a pergunta e explique melhor. Você só falou que precisava ter margem e sem surgir barra horizontal.